# Error while bringing up eth1

Tags: linux, networking, centos, linux-networking

I'm getting this error while bringing up my network card:

> (process:2550): WARNING **: _nm_object_get_property: Error getting
>   'State' for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3: (19)
>   Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface
>   "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist

I'm using the following commands:

```
1. ifup eth1
2. /etc/init.d/network restart
```

I have installed a fresh copy of Centos 6.2 and configured the network card.

Comment: The error message refers to NetworkManager while the commands you use are the older plain network service commands.  Are you using the NetworkManager service or the plain network service?  check `/sbin/chkconfig --list network` and `/sbin/chkconfig --list NetworkManager`.  Also please add what user account is used to execute these commands.

Comment: yeah i've checked NetworkManager services are off....this message appears while NetworkManager service are up while i'm bringing up my eth1 but i have disabled services #chkconfig --level 35 Networkmanager off and i am trying to activate my eth1 card without NetworkManager...i have made changes in ifcfg-eth1 file... nm_CONTROLLED="no" when NetworkManager services are off i don't see network notification icon on and if i go to system > preferance > network connection i don't see system eth0 or eth1 in wired tab.........Am i missing any step plz help me out to bring up eth1

Comment: Please post the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network` and `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1`

Comment: mhay, note there's a difference beween `nm_CONTROLLED="no"` and `NM_CONTROLLED="no"`.  Only the latter will work, while you say you've done the former.  If you do ever revisit SF, please post the contents of the files, as dotplus requests, above.

Answer (score 1):

Add `NM_CONTROLLED=no` to your `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` file.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have deleted the network Manager properties in the script written for bringing up the network interface, or network manager is not installed correctly or corrupted.

Comment: The OP is pretty clear that he's not trying to use NetworkManager to manage this interface at all, so that's probably not it.